# How long can pasteurized milk be refrigerated?

Tags: milk, boiling, storage-lifetime

The shop where I get milk (homogenized, pasteurized) is quite far from my home. So I would like to buy more milk per visit. Would like some expert advice on storing and handling the extra milk. How long can I use it safely? Would boiling this milk increase its fridge-life?

Thank you for your guidance.

Regards,
Simi

Comment: Do you have a freezer? That'll greatly extend its shelf life.

Answer (score 2):

Per [Still Tasty](http://www.eatbydate.com/dairy/milk/milk-shelf-life-expiration-date/), well refrigerated, milk should last about 5-7 days.  Note that this almost certainly assumes that the milk has been pasteurized.

It is theoretically possible that you could periodically reboil milk, and then try to get it cooled to refrigerator temperatures rapidly, to increase its life.   I suspect that the benefit would not justify the effort.

You can also freeze milk, if you have a freezer available.  It will last essentially indefinitely (there probably is a limit due to oxidation of the milk fat, but that is a slow process), and will still be quite suitable for cooking.

Depending on availability and how you use it, you may also wish to consider shelf stable milk products like dry powdered milk, condensed milk, or sweetened condensed milk.